# Check mutiple filename in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

[Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tixnj.png)Check with multiple filename and turn green color in the cell.
[Return at Cell C5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKgC9.png)

```
Found = Dir(FolderPath & "\" & "01 - Introduction" & " " & Range("B5") & "_v" & Range("B3") & ".*")
    Found1 = Dir(FolderPath & "\" & "02 - Business" & " " & Range("B5") & "_v" & Range("B3") & ".*")
    Found2 = Dir(FolderPath & "\" & "04 - Linking" & " " & Range("B5") & "_v" & Range("B3") & ".*")
    Found3 = Dir(FolderPath & "\" & "05 - Data" & " " & Range("B5") & "_v" & Range("B3") & ".*")
    Found4 = Dir(FolderPath & "\" & "06 - Conclusion" & " " & Range("B5") & "_v" & Range("B3") & ".*")
    Found5 = Dir(FolderPath & "\" & "Systems_ABC" & "_v" & Range("B3") & ".*")

If Found <> "" & Found1 <> "" & Found2 <> "" & Found3 <> "" & Found4 <> "" & Found5 <> "" Then
    Range("C5").Interior.ColorIndex = 4
Else
    Range("C5").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End If
```

the code are not working, even I change the filename, the cell still will return green color.

Comment: Can you please provide us with some example data, as well as results you are getting vs what you are expecting to get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Change this:**

```
If Found <> "" & Found1 <> "" & Found2 <> "" & Found3 <> "" & Found4 <> "" & Found5 <> "" Then
    Range("C5").Interior.ColorIndex = 4
Else
    Range("C5").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End If
```

**With This:**

```
If Found <> "" And Found1 <> "" And Found2 <> "" And Found3 <> "" And Found4 <> "" And Found5 <> "" Then
    Range("C5").Interior.ColorIndex = 4
Else
    Range("C5").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End If
```

`And` is accepted like this. Also I am assuming that your `DIR` are all working fine.

Comment: Yay! that's the answer! Thank you so much!

Comment: Happy to help :) @Yangx